# swift 5 autoresizingMask not working at all

Tags: ios, swift, autoresizingmask

I'm familiar with Autolayout programmingly but I also want to try autoresizingMask programmingly. I have a green box created and want center it horizontally, but fixed distance for top and bottom, however whatever I tried any combination of autoresizingMask it never work.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    view.autoresizesSubviews = true
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

    let myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 175, y: 100, width: 30, height: 30))
    myView.backgroundColor = .green
    view.addSubview(myView)
    myView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleRightMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin]
}
```

I tried it on iphone SE2 and iphone 11 Pro Max, the green block is centered on SE but never on Pro Max, anyone know what is going on?

Comment: So you are not actually centering the view, so in what sense were you hoping this view would be "centered"?

Comment: just want to center it horizontally

Comment: Well you are still not centering it even horizontally.

Comment: I actually want to do is to test if autoresizing is working. however if I tried to place the green box left fixed size and flexible righ margin is still now working

Comment: overall, autoresizingMask is acting like nobody in ios, nothing work if I applied any one of them or any combination.

Comment: Well, you don't know what to expect because you don't understand what autoresizing is. Maybe you should just stick to auto layout if you understand that better.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Look at it this way. Take the autoresizing code away and just set the frame. Does that frame center the view on every size of screen? No. Then adding back the autoresizing code won’t change that.

Answer (score 2):

What autoresizing does is to maintain the view according to its frame and the autoresizing mask. So the first step, if you want this view centered, is to *center* it:

```
myView.center = CGPoint(x:view.bounds.midX, y:view.bounds.midY)
```

Now make all four margins flexible, and the view will stay where you put it in relation to any screen size.

Answer (score 0):

By default the view is rigid and has constant distance to the top left corner. You are looking for a flexibleWidth and Height

```
autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
```